# Unable to locate Ant builder/deployer and jee-library .jar files

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have downloaded an iFix (6.1.0.02.20150520-1015) for Worklight Server and Worklight Studio but I could not locate the below files.

- worklight-ant-builder.jar
- worklight-ant-deployer.jar
- worklight-jee-library.jar

Comment: Did you *install* the iFix? Did it install successfully?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier,  Still not tried yet, wanted to confirm if these files get generated post installation and can be copied to mac machines which can be further used by jenkins to build the Apps ?

Comment: Those files are part of the installed image. You won't see them in the iFix until you install it.

Comment: can you open a separate question as a separate question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files are extracted to the destination you specified during the installation process when using the IBM Installation Manager. So that would be: `WL_INSTALL_DIR`.

You will need to use the Ant builder and deployer .jar files for when generating and building/deploying your project's .war, .wlapp and .adapter files.

The JEE library .jar file is used by the installation Ant task script in order to update the server with it.

These are .jar files and are the same files you would use in any operating system; you can copy them where ever you'd like to.

For more information see this user documentation topic: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_ov_server_install.html

Comment: I think you have that wrong. These files are normally installed to the base WL_INSTALL_DIR itself (e.g. /opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer).

Comment: yep, I just checked it. Edited.

Comment: @IdanAdar , So post WL server installation these jar files would be created automatically on WL_INSTALL_DIR , also these jars are specific to each version of worklight provided by IBM Fix central ?

Comment: They are extracted by the installation process to the folder, yes. And yes, you should use the same version of jar for every upgrade - don't mix versions.

Comment: @djrecker, Did this answer not answer your question?

Comment: I've also mentioned that you can use these files anywhere.